# How do I escape Trackback or any kind of errors Errors?

Tags: python, exception

How to write a proper statement on escaping an ERROR in python... suppose

Example

```
import base64
encode = base64.b64encode(raw_input('Enter Data: '))
data = base64.b64decode(encode)
print 'Your Encoded Message is: ' + encode
print '.'
print '.'
print '.'
print '.'
print '.'
decode = base64.b64decode(raw_input('Enter Encoded Data: '))
data2 = base64.b64decode(encode)
print 'Your Encoded Message is: ' + decode
```

Now This script only does is Encode and Decode raw data. Error occurs when I enter normal raw data into `'Enter Encoded Data: '`
How am I suppose to Escape errors something like Sorry! the Data you Have put is to be Encoded.

Instead of Trackback garbage.

Comment: Why are you double decoding it?

Comment: [`try: b64decode(...) except Exception as e: ...`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a try-except: statement

```
decode = None
while not decode:
   try:
      decode = base64.b64decode(raw_input('Enter Encoded Data: '))
      data2 = base64.b64decode(encode)
   except:
      print 'Sorry! the Data you Have put is to be Encoded.'
print 'Your Encoded Message is: ' + decode
```

Comment: Please don't instruct anyone to use a catch-all exception. There's a very specific exception here that can occur, all other exceptions should be handled somewhere else.

Comment: you are correct. however seeing as he doesn't understand exception handling at all, i believe this is a straight forward beginning example.

Answer (score 1):

When you get errors, usually some function (like `base64.b64decode`) is raising an [`Exception`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions). You can "catch" Exceptions by wrapping procedures that might create them in what's called a `try`-`except` block, like this:

```
try:
    # Stuff that might raise an Exception goes in here
    decode = base64.b64decode(raw_input('Enter Encoded Data: '))
except Exception as e:
    # Execute this block if an Exception is raised in the try block.
    print('Sorry! The input data must be encoded!')
```

If you know exactly the kind of `Exception`s you're getting (the error message will tell you), you should should specify that *exact* exception in your `except` block, so that you don't [accidentally hide other kinds of errors](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except). For instance, `base64.b64decode` generally raises `binascii.Error` when it receives improper input, so you can `except` that error specifically. That way, if something different goes wrong, you'll notice it!

```
import binascii
try:
    decode = base64.b64decode(raw_input('Enter Encoded Data: '))
except binascii.Error as e:
    print('Sorry! The input data must be b64 encoded!')
```

Exception handling is really an important part of good coding practice, as you've already discovered, so make sure to take a look at the Python documentation in the link above!